# Is there any user space SDIO driver in Linux?

Tags: linux, drivers, sdio

sdio_driver in kernel:

Just 1 sdio_driver in "linux-2.6-daf54f1\drivers\mmc\card" (sdio_uart)

There are some in linux-2.6-daf54f1\drivers\net\wireless.

My questions are:

1. Is there any user space SDIO driver in Linux?
2. Is it possible?

Comment: Is what possible?

Answer (score 1):

check out patch submitted to linux-mmc mailing list.
http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.mmc/22781/focus=22783

Comment: The related [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387755/45713) also mentions the option to use bind/unbind.

Comment: Based on another related [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291741/45713), if you are using a TI SDIO device it won't work without the interrupt.