# How can one force a re-scan of an SDIO bus from Linux user space?

Tags: embedded, sd-card, sdio

On an embedded Linux platform, I have a network adapter attached to an SDIO interface. There is no Card Detect signal on this particular bus. If for instance, I turn the network adapter power on or off, is there any way I can force a re-scan of the SDIO bus from user space?

Comment: does the code within `/usr/bin/rescan-scsi-bus.sh` do this ?

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned by 0andriy, you can use bind/unbind. I am doing something similar but this will be different as it depends on the hardware. To unbind my sdio wifi module I use:

```
echo -n "2190000.usdhc" > /sys/devices/soc0/soc/2100000.aips-bus/2190000.usdhc/driver/unbind
```

This will give you something like `mmc1: card 0001 removed` in dmesg.

I then toggle a gpio pin to reset my wifi module

Then to rebind:

```
echo -n "2190000.usdhc" > /sys/bus/soc/devices/soc0/soc/2100000.aips-bus/2190000.usdhc/subsystem/drivers/sdhci-esdhc-imx/bind
```

At which point dmesg will print something like:

```
mmc1: SDHCI controller on 2190000.usdhc [2190000.usdhc] using ADMA
mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
```

Binding/unbinding process is explained well by this old [LWN.net article](https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/).

Comment: Note that based on the related [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291741/45713), if you are using a TI SDIO device it won't work without the interrupt.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there was a [patch submitted](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.mmc/22781/focus=22783) to the linux-mmc mailing list to add this feature, however looking at [the current source](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/mmc/core/host.c), it doesn't appear to have been added.

So unfortunately I guess this makes the answer: you can't.

Comment: It's not fully true. Easiest way to work around is to unbind / bind cycle of the host controller. Also there is another way to simulate card detection in the driver, but it might be non-upstreamable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to follow the steps specified in Marius's answer in beaglebone black to successfully unbind and bind a WiFi chip connected to the mmc2(there are 3 SDIO interfaces in beaglebone mmc0, mmc1, mmc2) interface. But the path to the mmc2 interface in beaglebone black(this is tested on a Beaglebone Rev C board running the IoT Buster image) is a little different.

To unbind the sdio module execute the below command as root:
`echo -n "47810000.mmc" > /sys/devices/platform/soc/subsystem/devices/47810000.mmc/driver/unbind`

To bind the module:
`echo -n "47810000.mmc" > /sys/devices/platform/soc/subsystem/devices/47810000.mmc/subsystem/drivers/omap_hsmmc/bind`